# Помогите отключить возможность вращения для polygon в Yandex.Maps

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, canvas

Пытаюсь реализовать возможность получать координаты выделенной прямоугольной области на YandexMaps. Загвоздка в том, что по умолчанию фигуру можно крутить, а пользователю этого делать нельзя.

```
yaForm = new ymaps.Polygon([
                [
                    [_center[0] - _step, _center[1] + _step],
                    [_center[0] + _step, _center[1] + _step],
                    [_center[0] + _step, _center[1] - _step],
                    [_center[0] - _step, _center[1] - _step],
                ]
            ], {}, {
                fillColor: _fillColor,
                strokeColor: _strokeColor,
                strokeOpacity: _strokeOpacity,
                strokeWidth: _strokeWidth,               
                editorFrameRotateIconLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="map-hidden"></div>'),
            });               

            yaMap.geoObjects.add(yaForm);                   
            yaForm.editor.startFraming();
```

Добавляю класс "map-hidden" к иконке вращения, но остается линия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-то знает можно вообще отключить эту опцию или хотя-бы скрыть линию?

Answer (score 1):

Прошу прощения за некропостинг, но вдруг кому-то пригодится - чтобы скрыть контрол поворота полигона необходимо прокинуть в опциях

```
editorFrameRotationControlDisabled: true
```

И тогда он не будет рендерится[image: введите сюда описание изображения]